# Vue v-for list not re-rendering after computed data update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am implementing pagination for a huge list of cards, I display 10 cards at once and wish to show the 10 next (or 10 previous) by clicking on two buttons.

Here's how I do it:

```
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {          
      pois: [], // My list of elements
      pageNumber: 0, // Current page number
    };
  },
  props: {
    size: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 10, // 10 cards per page
    },
  },
  computed: {
    pageCount() {
      // Counts the number of pages total
      const l = this.pois.length;
      const s = this.size;
      return Math.floor(l / s);
    },
    paginatedData() {
      // Returns the right cards based on the current page
      const start = this.pageNumber * this.size;
      const end = start + this.size;
      return this.pois.slice(start, end);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage() {
      this.pageNumber += 1;
    },
    prevPage() {
      this.pageNumber -= 1;
    },
  }
  ...
};
```

And my template:

```
<div v-for="poi in paginatedData" :key="poi.id">                
  <card :poi="poi"/>
</div>
```

Everything should work (and a page change does output the correct cards in the console) but my list is not updated even though the computed method is called on each click.

What is causing this issue? I've read it could be linked to a `:key` value missing, but it's there, and no data is being updated directly and manually in the array, only sliced out.

Comment: Can it be, that the `poi.id` has the same value on each object in your array?

Comment: Each ID is unique in this case

Comment: try with index key: `<div v-for="(poi, key) in paginatedData" :key="key">`

Comment: @Christopher your code works ([proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/z0y435om/)). Maybe your issue is about how you fetch you data (pois)

Answer (score 0):

First, try this change, just for sure, and let me know in comment it works or not.

```
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    paginatedData() {
      ...
      const end = start + this.size - 1;
      ...
    },
  ...
};
```

And yes: instead of id, try to use index:

```
<div v-for="(poi, idx) in paginatedData" :key="idx">                
  <card :poi="poi"/>
</div>
```